Set SPI Mode on Arduino Uno R4
I am switching a code from Arduino Uno R3 to Arduino Uno R4 Wifi due to the limitation of RAM spaces on R3. I use a thermocouple shield and SD Card read/write shield with the project, which requires me to transfer between mode 3 and mode 0 on R3. However, when I try to do the following code on R4:
SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE3); 

The IDE told me that SPI does not have a function named setDataMode. I tried to run the program without using setDataMode, but it does not seem work correctly (SD Cards with empty data).
Compilation error: 'class arduino::ArduinoSPI' has no member named 'setDataMode'

Thank you all for helping. the issue is resolve by using SPISettings variable along with SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings) and SPI.endTransaction(SPISettings)

The text is pretty much what described in the question, it says: Compilation error: 'class arduino::ArduinoSPI' has no member named 'setDataMode', which this is the command to change data mode using Arduino UNO R3

the message text belongs in the question. not in a comment ... added it for you ... you can delete the comment

The first paragraph of the SPI.setDataMode() documentation said "This function should not be used in new projects. Use SPISettings. with SPI.beginTransaction(). to configure SPI parameters". I wish they could be more explicitly saying "This function is deprecated since 2014 and only exist for backward compatibility reason".

See my answer to a similar question for further explanation.

Thank you for the help @hcheung, the issue is resolved with 'SPISettings' and SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings)

I looked at SPI.h in the R4 core here:
https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-renesas/blob/main/libraries/SPI/SPI.h
It looks like you have to set up a configuration struct and pass to a different function:
arduino::SPISettings const DEFAULT_SPI_SETTINGS = arduino::SPISettings(1000000, MSBFIRST, arduino::SPI_MODE0);
    arduino::SPISettings _settings = arduino::SPISettings(0, MSBFIRST, arduino::SPI_MODE0);

Then in beginTransaction you have the opportunity to pass in those settings:
virtual void beginTransaction(arduino::SPISettings settings);

I'm not 100% sure how that all works, but at least this should get you going in the right direction.

Thanks for the help, you can reply to me either here or on the forum. I will be looking at both sides, and I will post solutions either from forum or from here once we have a solution

It would be better if you had only one post.  It's mostly the same people on both sites.  Your post there is probably better because there are a few of us that have been digging really deep on the R4.

Have you tried this?  Create the settings you need following the model in this answer and then try passing that to beginTransaction
